# Watch date input value and use it with v-model

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I tried for 4 days to get a stupid date from the input, that the user selected. Looks probably simple but believe me that I ask here because I run out of solutions.

I have a page/component AddNewEvent and inside this input where the user adds the date and time. I have to get it in my v-model so I can send it back to database.

I use bootstrap 4 input `type="datetime-local"` to get the date and time. I tried to use some vue plugins for date but all are based on bootstrap 3 and in the project is bootstrap 4.

Inside template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="eda-form-label" for="event-name">Event Name <span>(Max characters number is 60)</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="eda-form-input" v-model="newEvent.eventName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="eda-form-label" for="exampleTextarea">Event Description <span>(Max characters number is 2000)</span></label>
    <textarea class="eda-form-input" rows="3" v-model="newEvent.description"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 ">
      <label class="eda-form-label" for="start-time">START TIME</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" v-model="dateNow">
    </div>{{createdDate(value)}}
    <div class="col-6">
      <label class="eda-form-label" for="end-time">END TIME</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" v-model="dateEnd">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the script:

```
data() {
  return {
    dateNow: '',
    value: '',
    oldValue: ''
  }
},
watch: {
  dateNow(val, oldVal) {
    this.value = val;
    this.oldValue = oldVal;
  }
},
methods: {
    createEvent(){
      axios.post("/event", this.newEvent, 
          {'headers':{'X-AUTH-TOKEN': localStorage.token}},
          {'headers':{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
        .then((response) => {
          alertify.success("Success! You added a new the user"); 
          this.$router.push('/events');
        })
        .catch((response) => {
          alertify.error();

        })
    },
}
```

If I use in the input, how is right now, `v-model="dateNow"` works. I can see when I select date, time am/pm shows me the seleted date. But I have to use it like this

`v-model="newEvent.dateNow"`

`v-model="newEvent.dateEnd"`

so I can add it to newEvent and send the whole obj back to database.

createdDate is a function that transforms the date in a real date. It's only for testing, because I have to send the date in ms back to database.

Someone please show me what I do wrong, because I'm not so very advance in vuejs.

Comment: Seems to be missing a lot of the code.. include all relevant code as for example the el element in your Vue.js code

Comment: My friend here is happening what I can't solve. The user selects a date and time, the input is in the HTML and  I tried with watch to see the change, witch works, but not adding to newDate object how I want. You see that newEvent is defined, then is used to send that back to database with this.newEvent. What code is missing?

Comment: If someone will help you solve this problem many will usually test the answer before posting an answer and it will take extra time if they have to makeup code for what you have left out. You can then save them a lot of time by simplify your questions, your html could be 3-4 lines of code. The JavaScript is not complete, I assume you got a few more of lines above the data() element with 'var vm = new Vue({  el: '#demo'... '

Comment: beside what you see I have the import for axios, export default{} and that method createdDate, that is a js simple function. I don't need somethig else to have in this page because is a simple add with a few inputs, is not a complex page.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to initialize dateNow varable in datetime-locale:

```
data() {
  return {
    dateNow: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    value: '',
    oldValue: ''
  }
},
```

It support this format: "2017-09-18T08:30".
I think this will solve your problem.

And also you need to check **Browser compatibility**, as it is not supported in IE, Firefox and Safari

or you can try:

```
<input type="datetime-local" :value="dateValue" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" >
```

in script:

```
data() {
    return {
      dateValue: new Date().toLocaleString()
    };
  },
methods: {
   updateValue: function(value) {
      this.dateValue= value;
      this.$emit('input', value);
   }
}
```

Try this

Comment: My friend the date is showing ok but when I change the date and time in the input, I can't see it changing outside.

Comment: You can see in this picture that I select something but I can't see the changes: http://prntscr.com/gmlmwh

Comment: Why are you binding start date and end date with one model

Comment: I test it a lot and forgot to change it. Should be start and end.

Comment: That doesn't matter now. At least one input to work :).

Comment: you are getting new and old value in watch?

Comment: If I use it like this http://prntscr.com/gmlyin yes I get old and new value, but I have to use it like this: http://prntscr.com/gmlz8t . dateNow is a field in database so I get it like this event { 'eventName': 'aaa', 'description': 'bbbb', 'dateNow': 232132132131, 'dateEnd': '213213213343'}. So I use newEvent to get all what the user typed and selected and send this object back to database.